# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long ContatoDAO.alterar(Contato)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Erro:

```
09-12 14:05:28.662 10410-10410/costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais, PID: 10410
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.ContatoDAO.alterar(costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.Contato)' on a null object reference
at costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.TelaDetalhe$1.onClick(TelaDetalhe.java:158)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

DAO:

```
public class ContatoDAO {
public static final String TAG = "LogDAO";

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private BaseDAO dbHelper;

public ContatoDAO(Context contexto){
    dbHelper = new BaseDAO(contexto);
}

public void abrirBanco() {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void fecharBanco() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

//Cadastrar
public long cadastrar(Contato c) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOME, c.getNome());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_TELEFONE, c.getTelefone());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_EMPRESA, c.getEmpresa());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_BRUNKO, c.isBrunko());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_CARTER, c.isCarter());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_FORTMETAL, c.isFortmetal());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_MERCO, c.isMerco());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_METAN, c.isMetan());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NDFLEX, c.isNdflex());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOTUS, c.isNotus());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_RIOSULENSE, c.isRiosulense());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_YIMING, c.isYming());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_MES_CONTATO, c.getMesContato());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_ANO_CONTATO, c.getAnoContato());

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(c.isBrunko()));

    return database.insert(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, null, cv);
}

//Alterar
public long alterar(Contato c) {

    long id = c.getId();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOME, c.getNome());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_TELEFONE, c.getTelefone());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_EMPRESA, c.getEmpresa());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_BRUNKO, c.isBrunko());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_CARTER, c.isCarter());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_FORTMETAL, c.isFortmetal());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_MERCO, c.isMerco());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_METAN, c.isMetan());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NDFLEX, c.isNdflex());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOTUS, c.isNotus());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_RIOSULENSE, c.isRiosulense());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_YIMING, c.isYming());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_MES_CONTATO, c.getMesContato());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_ANO_CONTATO, c.getAnoContato());

    return database.update(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, cv, BaseDAO.CONTATO_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}

//Deletar
public long deletar(long id) {
    long identificador = id;

    return database.delete(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, BaseDAO.CONTATO_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(identificador)});
}
```

Tela para atualizar:

```
    btnAtualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            c.setNome(etNome.getText().toString());
            c.setTelefone(etTelefone.getText().toString());
            c.setEmpresa(etEmpresa.getText().toString());
            c.setBrunko(cbBrunko.isChecked());
            c.setCarter(cbCarter.isChecked());
            c.setFortmetal(cbFortmetal.isChecked());
            c.setMerco(cbMerco.isChecked());
            c.setMetan(cbMetan.isChecked());
            c.setNdflex(cbNdflex.isChecked());
            c.setNotus(cbNotus.isChecked());
            c.setRiosulense(cbRiosulense.isChecked());
            c.setYming(cbYiming.isChecked());
            c.setMesContato(spMesContato.getSelectedItemPosition());
            c.setAnoContato(spAnoContato.getSelectedItem().toString());

            cDAO.alterar(c);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contato alterado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btnDeletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Removendo do Banco
            cDAO.deletar(c.getId());

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contato excluído com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Como vc está instanciando o **cDAO**? Parece que ele não foi inicializado

Comment: private ContatoDAO cDAO; //Instancia da classe DAO

Comment: private ContatoDAO cDAO.. não está instanciada, falta um ContatoDAO cDAO = new ContatoDAO();

Comment: quando insiro Contato cDAO = new ContatoDAO(); pede o contexto, coloquei o inicio da classe dao ali em cima

Comment: O contexto é a sua própria classe, ou seja, é só colocar **this** aonde ele pede o contexto

Comment: Debugou e conferiu a instância dos objetos envolvidos? Pelo menos a linha do problema creio que conseguirá achar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ERRO:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
>   costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.ContatoDAO.alterar(costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.Contato)'
>   on a null object reference

O [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) é quando o sistema tenta acessar uma referencia que está nula!

Tradução livre do erro:

> Tentativa de invocar método virtual 'ContatoDAO.alterar long
>   (Contato)' em uma referência de objeto nulo

Então você está tentando passar um `null` a um objeto primitivo `long`.
Isto ocorre na seguinte linha:

```
  long id = c.getId();
```

Quando você solicita no `onClick` para salvar o objeto, não é informado o Id.

Caso seja uma alteração do objeto, guarde este Id em uma propriedade da Classe, e quando salvar, informe:

```
  c.setAnoContato(spAnoContato.getSelectedItem().toString());
  c.setId(idContato); // Id do contato que está sendo editado!
  cDAO = new ContatoDAO(TelaDetalhe.this);
  cDAO.alterar(c);
```

Agora, caso seja uma inclusão (um novo registro), ao invés de chamar o método `alterar` chame o `cadastrar`:

```
  c.setAnoContato(spAnoContato.getSelectedItem().toString());
  // Contato não tem id, vamos cadastrar um novo!
  cDAO = new ContatoDAO(TelaDetalhe.this);
  cDAO.cadastrar(c);
```

Comment: acho que entendi, mas quando eu passo o objeto c pelo it.putExtra(c, "contato"); o objeto c já tem o id no caso eu apenas setei os novos valor das outras variáveis. se eu colocar um log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(c)); o id não está vazio no caso ele tem o valor de 4

Comment: sim, sempre ocorre independentemente do id, o erro ocorre antes de chegar na classe DAO

Comment: o erro esta apontando para a linha do cDAO.alterar(c); e não chega nessa parte porque coloquei alguns Log.d na classe DAO e els não aparecem no android monitor, ou seja, sequer entra no método de alterar do DAO

Comment: Bele! como é  o nome da classe? onde está este botao?

Comment: o nome da classe DAO é contatoDAO.java, a da tela de atualização do contato é TelaDetalhe.java e o botão está na activity_tela_detalhe.xml é isso?

Comment: então faça assim antes de chamar o DAO **cDAO = new ContatoDAO(TelaDetalhe.this);**

Comment: Como você está dentro do **onClickListener** para chamar a Contexto usa se **TelaDetalhe.this**  Editei a resposta para entender mehor

Comment: entendi e funcionou só que agora aparece um novo erro parecido com o de antes só que referente a linha do comando sql do alterar

Comment: Se o erro for diferente, peço por favor, que abra uma nova pergunta! assim facilita aos próximos usuários que procurarem no site! ok?

Comment: já fiz isso, link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236765/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-object-reference