# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Erro:

> ```
> 09-12 17:13:09.088
> 26022-26022/costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Process: costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais, PID: 26022
>    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(java.lang.String,
> android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])'
> on a null object reference
>        at costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.ContatoDAO.alterar(ContatoDAO.java:83)
>        at costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.TelaDetalhe$1.onClick(TelaDetalhe.java:153)
>        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
>        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
>        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>
> 09-12 17:26:05.946
> 26198-26198/costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Process: costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais, PID: 26198
>    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
>        at costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.ContatoDAO.deletar(ContatoDAO.java:90)
>        at costamilam.guilherme.contatosempresariais.TelaDetalhe$2.onClick(TelaDetalhe.java:172)
>        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
>        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
>        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
> ```

Tela:

```
public class TelaDetalhe extends AppCompatActivity {

private ContatoDAO cDAO; //Instancia da classe DAO

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_detalhe);

    final Contato c = (Contato) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("contato");

    btnAtualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            long contatoId = c.getId();

            c.setId(contatoId);
            c.setNome(etNome.getText().toString());
            c.setTelefone(etTelefone.getText().toString());
            c.setEmpresa(etEmpresa.getText().toString());

            cDAO = new ContatoDAO(TelaDetalhe.this);
            cDAO.alterar(c);
           
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contato alterado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btnDeletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Removendo do Banco
            cDAO = new ContatoDAO(TelaDetalhe.this);
            cDAO.deletar(c.getId());

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contato excluído com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
 
}
}
```

DAO:

```
public class ContatoDAO {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private BaseDAO dbHelper;

public ContatoDAO(Context contexto){
    dbHelper = new BaseDAO(contexto);
}

public void abrirBanco() {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void fecharBanco() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

//Alterar
public long alterar(Contato c) {
    long id = c.getId();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOME, c.getNome());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_TELEFONE, c.getTelefone());
    cv.put(BaseDAO.CONTATO_EMPRESA, c.getEmpresa());

    return database.update(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, cv, BaseDAO.CONTATO_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}

//Deletar
public long deletar(long id) {
    long identificador = id;

    return database.delete(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, BaseDAO.CONTATO_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(identificador)});
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, sugerimos que realize um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site e veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Assim, facilita a comunidade a te ajudar!

Comment: Acho que deu uma organizada agora

Comment: Esse NullPointerException é um indício de que você não iniciou com `abrirBanco` ou já fechou a `fecharBanco`

Comment: Foi esse mesmo o problema, quando passei o alterar para uma nova tela (antes era num alert) esqueci de abrir o banco. Muito obrigado Jefferson Quesado

Comment: O problema é parecido porém diferentes Carlos Heuberger, no primeiro faltos instanciar o classe DAO e aqui o problema foi por causa que o banco não foi aberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta está nos comentários e foi dada pelo Jefferson Quesado, mas só pra colocar aqui como resposta...

"Esse NullPointerException é um indício de que você não iniciou com abrirBanco ou já fechou a fecharBanco – Jefferson Quesado"